# Change the layout of an existing GTK2 application

Tags: gtk

For my daily work I use [Xournal](http://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/) to take notes with my ThinkPad X220 Tablet's pen input. The inconvenient thing is that even in full screen there are two toolbars at the top of the screen. It looks like this:

[image: Current layout of Xournal]

I have the page on roughly 100% actual A4 paper size. There is unused area on the left and right as this is a 16:9 screen. The digitizer is also non-linear on the left and right screen edges, so I like to stay clear of that when writing.

With the current setup I have only so much height. The toolbars could move to the left or right to give more height, like so:

[image: Desired layout of Xournal]

Each icon would be oriented normally, I just did not do that in the quick mock-up.

I cloned the git repository and found a `xournal.glade` file as well as `src/xo-interface.{c,h}`. The version of Glade on Fedora 23 complains about the old format of the `.glade` file so I converted it with `gtk-builder-convert xournal.glade xournal-new.glade` and was able to open the new file.

My only GUI experience is with Qt and Qt Designer. I looked into the UI widgets and found the layout contains which I can set from “horizontal” to “vertical”. The whole window is contained in a “vbox”. So in the XML code of the original, non-converted `xournal.glade` file I changed the `HORIZONTAL` to `VERTICAL` and `vbox` to `hbox`. When I recompile the project with `make` the UI looks just the same.

I thought that I perhaps have to generate some C code from within Glade but could not find anything. The Makefile apparently did not invoke anything that would convert it to C code.

How can I get the UI change to manifest in the new compilation?

## Update 2016-05-15

Now I have a bit more time to dig into this. First I found out that `xournal.glade` is not really used within the compilation process. Changing anything there did not affect the program. Running `strace src/xournal` on the compiled version I saw that it did not use any `.glade` file there. Therefore the UI must be compiled into the program. This step cannot be automatic, I did not find anything in the makefiles.

On Fedora 23, opening `xournal.glade` results in many errors, deprecation warnings and so on. It took me until today to realize that I can install `glade-2` and open that. This worked flawlessly. I could change the sorting order and replaced the layout to flow the other way around. The export feature updated `src/xo-interface.c` and after compilation I actually saw the changed version:

[image]

This is just what I want! Now I would have to see whether there is anything I could do to change this at run-time and make it a feature addition instead of just an incompatible fork.

Comment: Did you change `VBox` to `HBox` as well?

Comment: I think I changed some `vbox` to a `hbox` but I am not sure about `VBox`. The problem also was that none of the changes that were apparent in Glade after a single change appeared in the compiled program. So I suspect that there is some trick to get the Glade file compiled into the program :-/.

Comment: Look into the source code to see how the `.glade` file is loaded. My guess is that it's looking for the `.glade` file in the install prefix... (GTK+ 3 does have a way to embed the `.glade` (now `.ui`) file inside the binary, called GResource, but IDK if GTK+ 2 can use it.) You'll need to change from `VBox` to `HBox` to handle the class names — they are shown in the XML file as `GtkVBox`.

Comment: Did you ever go anywhere with this?

Comment: No, due to the lack of time I have not looked into that yet. But today I want to work on it :-)